# Admob makes app unresponsive on bad connection

Tags: javascript, cordova, admob, phonegap

I am using [admob pro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) for my Cordova app and face the issue that creating the banner makes the app unresponsive for almost 20 seconds if there is a bad internet connection.
I thought admob is doing the request in a seperate thread?

This is how I initialize it, it happens inside the `deviceReady` event.

```
AdMob.createBanner({
      adId: xxx,
      position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
      autoShow: false,
      isTesting:false
    }, function() {
      app.bannerCreated=true
    }, function(err) {
      if (app.isDebug) app.log('banner creation failed: '+err, true)
    })
```

Comment: You can use [network information plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/) and control if there is no internet connection and restart application? I was using [this one](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova) and never had any problem...

Comment: I just got news from the user that it does work when there is no internet enabled but only doesn't work when the connection is bad. I am already using the network plugin to check whether there is internet or not and only initialize the ads if internet is available. You never faced problems with bad connections using your admob plugin?

Comment: Well, it's the same if internet connection is bad and you are trying to enter in some website(loading...). But for banner there is no need for great connection, it's just simple photo with link... If you have problem with reward video ads, that's another story. 
You can try do it with that plugin, there is no blocking / freezing if internet connection is bad, ads wont display until connection  does not start to be better